# How does adding sulfuric acid to water affect the specific heat capacity of the solution?

Tags: acid-base

How does adding diffrent concentrations of sulfuric acid to water affect the specific heat capacity of the solution?

Comment: Review the guide [How to ask](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) and [Asking FAQs](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/asking) to prevent clarification requests, objections,  down-voting or closure.

Answer (score 1):

A, S. Socolik, Z. Phys. Chem. $158$A, $305 - 312, (1932)$ gives the following heat capacities for the mixtures $\ce{H2SO4}$ + $\ce{H2O}$ at different mass percent at $20$°C:

% $\ce{H2SO4}$ .... $\ce{C_p}$ in cal/g/K

..$0$% -----------  $1.000$

$12$% -----------  $0.900$

$24$% -----------  $0.812$

$36$% ----------- $0.715$

$48$% ----------- $0.611$

$60$% ----------- $0.525$

$72$% ----------- $0.464$

$84$% ----------- $0.441$

$92$% ----------- $0.372$

$100$% ---------  $0.332$